# Flutter: How to get NFC message after app starts

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc

I need to obtain the NFC message in the flutter App, after the App is opened by OS from tagging a NFC chip.

I believe it is achievable in native Android or iOS (though I haven't tried myself), link to the official docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#obtain-info
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading

However, the Flutter NFC plugin like `nfc_in_flutter` or `nfc_manager` only supports in-app NFC operations.

How can I do that?

If there's no current solution to the Flutter app, I'd love to learn how to code flutter plugin and implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For Android at least you should be able to use https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent as it is just the System NFC App sharing data with your App via a Standard `Intent`. So just put the correct manifest filters in for NFC Intents to get sent the right `Intent`'s and then read the right keys in the Intent for NFC as the docs.

Not tested and don't know about iOS

Comment: Thanks Andrew, will try to implement while looking for iOS solutions

Comment: I manage to make it work on Android by writing my own plugin, but NFC on iOS is a pain,  and Apple is really bad at documentation.

Comment: Apple reference documentation is not bad, it's examples are not existent, but NFC support is way behind Android's as the most basic of operations were only just supported in iOS 13. I stay away from iOS because of it's poor support but do have a reasonable understanding of how it works (enough to know to not even bother trying to do what I do on Android).

Comment: I managed to make it work on IOS, by using a custom scheme (or is it called universal link?) But you can go like: 
`myApp://hostname/path...`
And handle the payload in the swift code (similar to the official documentation code sample)

Comment: @xmanreturn Can you share your plugin pls?

Comment: @MarkoKarajlovic Sorry Marko for the late reply, my plugin is called nfc_info, https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_info